# Looking for /trade API endpoint information?

Tags: coinbase-api

Is there any way (via the API) to trade / convert between currencies?  For example, within a Coinbase account, we can trade (or convert) BTC to ETH.   But what endpoint allows us to do this via the API -- the documentation seems to be missing any reference to a /v2/trade endpoint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did find a way to trade please ? The api with transfer currencies between account it still not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083976/coinbase-api-transfermoney-any-update-confirmation-it-is-working